# Getting "Downloading... Do not turn off target!" when trying to boot into recovery mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, recovery-mode

I just installed Cyanogenmod on my Samsung Galaxy S2. I want to
install Google Services app ZIP. For that I have to reboot the phone in recovery mode. But it is only showing

> Downloading... Do not turn off target!

What should be done?

Comment: Remove battery,put it back and hold Volume Up and Power at the same time until you see the Samsung logo appear.This will let you install gapps.zip

Comment: @SharathKumar thanks i did the same i got below options now how to install zip?
//reboot system now //apply update //wipe data/factory reset //wipe cache partition //reboot to bootloader //power down //view log –

Comment: apply update -> install from internal storage -> locate the zip

Answer (score 1):

You have rebooted to Download Mode by mistake. You needed to reboot to recovery mode. To do that, follow these steps:

1. Press the Power button until the phone reboots normally.
2. Switch off the phone as normal.
3. When the phone has been switched off, press Power and Volume Up together until the Samsung logo displays, then release.

Alternative:

1. Reboot to system
2. Find the "Advanced Power Menu" option under phone customization settings, and enable it.
3. Press the Power button to get the power menu, and choose "Reboot → Reboot to Recovery".

That's it. I think you have a custom recovery installed and can find your way about it.

**Edit:**

So you don't have a custom recovery installed and have the stock recovery. I have no idea how you installed Cyanogenmod without a custom recovery (so please include the process of how you did it in your question), maybe through ODIN? If so, flashing a custom recovery like CWM or TWRP is similar in process to the way you flashed CWM/TWRP. I'll point you to a guide on how to do this [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73232/install-cwm-on-samsung-galaxy-s2-gt-9100m/73240?s=6%7C0.1135#73240).

Comment: Viewers, if you have a more detailed guide on enabling the advanced per menu in CM, please edit it into the answer instead of downvoting it.

Comment: There is no vote as of now but I believe your first revision could've caused that: http://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/127645/1 since it was a one-liner.

Comment: I got recoivery mode but no option to install zip file :(
Options are- 
reboot system now
apply update
wipe data/factory reset
wiipe cache partition
reboot to bootloader
power down
view log

Comment: @Neo then your custom recovery didnt stick, try it again. If it doesnt work look for TWRP or Philz recovery and try one of them.